# How do I remove excessive `clone` calls from a struct that caches arbitrary results?

Tags: rust

I am reading [the section on closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html#storing-closures-using-generic-parameters-and-the-fn-traits) in the second edition of the Rust book. At the end of this section, there is an exercise to extend the `Cacher` implementation given before. I gave it a try:

```
use std::clone::Clone;
use std::cmp::Eq;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

struct Cacher<T, K, V>
where
    T: Fn(K) -> V,
    K: Eq + Hash + Clone,
    V: Clone,
{
    calculation: T,
    values: HashMap<K, V>,
}

impl<T, K, V> Cacher<T, K, V>
where
    T: Fn(K) -> V,
    K: Eq + Hash + Clone,
    V: Clone,
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T, K, V> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            values: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn value(&mut self, arg: K) -> V {
        match self.values.clone().get(&arg) {
            Some(v) => v.clone(),
            None => {
                self.values
                    .insert(arg.clone(), (self.calculation)(arg.clone()));
                self.values.get(&arg).unwrap().clone()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After creating a version that finally works, I am really unhappy with it. What really bugs me is that `cacher.value(...)` has 5(!) calls to `clone()` in it. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct, the code contains too many calls to `clone()`, defeating the very optimizations `Cacher` is designed to achieve.

## Cloning the entire cache

The one to start with is the call to `self.values.clone()` - it creates a copy of the entire cache *on every single access*.

### After non-lexical lifetimes

Remove this clone.

### Before non-lexical lifetimes

As you likely discovered yourself, simply removing `.clone()` doesn't compile. This is because the borrow checker considers the map referenced for the entire duration of `match`. The shared reference returned by `HashMap::get` points to the item inside the map, which means that while it exists, it is forbidden to create another mutable reference to the same map, which is required by `HashMap::insert`. For the code to compile, you need to split up the match in order to force the shared reference to go out of scope before `insert` is invoked:

```
// avoids unnecessary clone of the whole map
fn value(&mut self, arg: K) -> V {
    if let Some(v) = self.values.get(&arg).map(V::clone) {
        return v;
    } else {
        let v = (self.calculation)(arg.clone());
        self.values.insert(arg, v.clone());
        v
    }
}
```

---

This is much better and probably "good enough" for most practical purposes. The hot path, where the value is already cached, now consists of only a single clone, and that one is actually necessary because the original value must remain in the hash map. (Also, note that cloning doesn't need to be expensive or imply deep copying - the stored value can be an `Rc<RealValue>`, which buys object sharing for free. In that case, `clone()` will simply increment the reference count on the object.)

## Clone on cache miss

In case of cache miss, the key must be cloned, because `calculation` is declared to consume it. A single cloning will be sufficient, though, so we can pass the original `arg` to `insert` without cloning it again. The key clone still feels unnecessary, though - a calculation function shouldn't require ownership of the key it is transforming. Removing this clone boils down to modifying the signature of the calculation function to take the key by reference. Changing the trait bounds of `T` to `T: Fn(&K) -> V` allows the following formulation of `value()`:

```
// avoids unnecessary clone of the key
fn value(&mut self, arg: K) -> V {
    if let Some(v) = self.values.get(&arg).map(V::clone) {
        return v;
    } else {
        let v = (self.calculation)(&arg);
        self.values.insert(arg, v.clone());
        v
    }
}
```

## Avoiding double lookups

Now are left with exactly two calls to `clone()`, one in each code path. This is optimal, as far as value cloning is concerned, but the careful reader will still be nagged by one detail: in case of cache miss, the hash table lookup will effectively happen *twice* for the same key: once in the call to `HashMap::get`, and then once more in `HashMap::insert`. It would be nice if we could instead reuse the work done the first time and perform only one hash map lookup. This can be achieved by replacing `get()` and `insert()` with `entry()`:

```
// avoids the second lookup on cache miss
fn value(&mut self, arg: K) -> V {
    match self.values.entry(arg) {
        Entry::Occupied(entry) => entry.into_mut(),
        Entry::Vacant(entry) => {
            let v = (self.calculation)(entry.key());
            entry.insert(v)
        }
    }.clone()
}
```

We've also taken the opportunity to move the `.clone()` call after the match.

Runnable example [in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b7f71a884da5d13203c548e756ed0cf3).

Comment: Really nice! Thank you very much. I also needed to include `std::collections::hash_map::Entry` to make the final refactoring work. :-)
Also I could drop the `Clone` trait from K, as it is not cloned anymore.

Comment: @itmuckel The [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3d37ef944b512f0ae265f3b1e5f22beb&version=stable) at the end of the answer contains the compilable code that includes the necessary import. I've now also updated it not to require `Clone` from `K`, good catch.

Comment: @user4815162342: nice explanation! I wonder what do you think about Andrei Tomashpolskiy's approach in his answer - returning a reference bound by Cacher's lifetime?

Comment: @Gruffalo Looking most generally, the other answer can provide even better performance, because the user of the API can choose whether to `clone` or to maybe extract only a small part of the value. This of course comes at the cost of changing the signature of `Cacher::value`, which I didn't want to do and I can't tell whether the exercise even allows. (In the book, the result is a `u32` which is `Clone + Copy`, so it's a moot point.)

Comment: Also, note that the reference is not bound by the lifetime of `Cacher`, but by the lifetime of the mutable reference to the `Cacher`. As soon as you want to mutate the `Cacher`, e.g. by calling `Cacher::value` with a different key, you'll need to drop the old reference and along it the reference returned by `Cacher::value`.

Answer (score 2):

I was solving the same exercise and ended with the following code:

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::fmt::Display;

struct Cacher<P, R, T>
where
    T: Fn(&P) -> R,
    P: Eq + Hash + Clone,
{
    calculation: T,
    values: HashMap<P, R>,
}

impl<P, R, T> Cacher<P, R, T>
where
    T: Fn(&P) -> R,
    P: Eq + Hash + Clone,
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<P, R, T> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            values: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn value<'a>(&'a mut self, key: P) -> &'a R {
        let calculation = &self.calculation;
        let key_copy = key.clone();
        self.values
            .entry(key_copy)
            .or_insert_with(|| (calculation)(&key))
    }
}
```

It only makes a single copy of the key in the `value()` method. It does not copy the resulting value, but instead returns a reference with a lifetime specifier, which is equal to the lifetime of the enclosing `Cacher` instance (which is logical, I think, because values in the map will continue to exist until the `Cacher` itself is dropped).

Here's a test program:

```
fn main() {
    let mut cacher1 = Cacher::new(|num: &u32| -> u32 {
        println!("calculating slowly...");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
        *num
    });

    calculate_and_print(10, &mut cacher1);
    calculate_and_print(20, &mut cacher1);
    calculate_and_print(10, &mut cacher1);

    let mut cacher2 = Cacher::new(|str: &&str| -> usize {
        println!("calculating slowly...");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
        str.len()
    });

    calculate_and_print("abc", &mut cacher2);
    calculate_and_print("defghi", &mut cacher2);
    calculate_and_print("abc", &mut cacher2);
}

fn calculate_and_print<P, R, T>(intensity: P, cacher: &mut Cacher<P, R, T>)
where
    T: Fn(&P) -> R,
    P: Eq + Hash + Clone,
    R: Display,
{
    println!("{}", cacher.value(intensity));
}
```

And its output:

```
calculating slowly...
10
calculating slowly...
20
10
calculating slowly...
3
calculating slowly...
6
3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the requirement of returning values, you don't need to perform *any* clones by making use of the [`Entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html):

```
use std::{
    collections::{hash_map::Entry, HashMap},
    fmt::Display,
    hash::Hash,
    thread,
    time::Duration,
};

struct Cacher<P, R, T>
where
    T: Fn(&P) -> R,
    P: Eq + Hash,
{
    calculation: T,
    values: HashMap<P, R>,
}

impl<P, R, T> Cacher<P, R, T>
where
    T: Fn(&P) -> R,
    P: Eq + Hash,
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<P, R, T> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            values: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn value<'a>(&'a mut self, key: P) -> &'a R {
        let calculation = &self.calculation;

        match self.values.entry(key) {
            Entry::Occupied(e) => e.into_mut(),
            Entry::Vacant(e) => {
                let result = (calculation)(e.key());
                e.insert(result)
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut cacher1 = Cacher::new(|num: &u32| -> u32 {
        println!("calculating slowly...");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
        *num
    });

    calculate_and_print(10, &mut cacher1);
    calculate_and_print(20, &mut cacher1);
    calculate_and_print(10, &mut cacher1);

    let mut cacher2 = Cacher::new(|str: &&str| -> usize {
        println!("calculating slowly...");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
        str.len()
    });

    calculate_and_print("abc", &mut cacher2);
    calculate_and_print("defghi", &mut cacher2);
    calculate_and_print("abc", &mut cacher2);
}

fn calculate_and_print<P, R, T>(intensity: P, cacher: &mut Cacher<P, R, T>)
where
    T: Fn(&P) -> R,
    P: Eq + Hash,
    R: Display,
{
    println!("{}", cacher.value(intensity));
}
```

You could then choose to wrap this in another struct that performed a clone:

```
struct ValueCacher<P, R, T>
where
    T: Fn(&P) -> R,
    P: Eq + Hash,
    R: Clone,
{
    cacher: Cacher<P, R, T>,
}

impl<P, R, T> ValueCacher<P, R, T>
where
    T: Fn(&P) -> R,
    P: Eq + Hash,
    R: Clone,
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            cacher: Cacher::new(calculation),
        }
    }

    fn value(&mut self, key: P) -> R {
        self.cacher.value(key).clone()
    }
}
```